# How to model a non member aggregate in UML class diagram

Tags: oop, uml

In the below UML diagram, Account has an aggregation of Orders. Based on most online resources, this would typically mean Account class has something similar to a List as an instance.

But in reality, for a real world web app with persistent storage, that is not usually how the Account Class would be. It won't have a list of orders as instance. Instead some other controller class will just query a datastore asking for all Orders belonging to an Account. So in a UML class diagram for such an app, is this still the right way to represent relations? The cardinality and maybe the concept of aggregation looks right from a database entity perspective. Just that the diamond makes no sense from a Class perspective.

Or should it show a DataStore/DataManager with a getOrdersForAccount() method and connect it to Account class and Orders class through a dependency relation (dotted line with arrow) ?

[image]

Comment: What is your concern: database design or OOP class design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on what you want to represent.

The class model you have already would be sufficient as a *logical domain model*, expressing the logical relationships between entities in your domain. This might not be how you implement your software in code precisely, but it will guide you (and others) in understanding the entities and their relationships without getting bogged down in that implementation detail. At this level, your diagram may have a few design choices (strong aggregation for example is arguably a design choice, but it may not be, as is the use of enumerations and keys) but not that many and nothing that really detracts from the underlying logic. If anything, you could loose some design choices here and improve the expression of logic.

What you may also want is to provide a representation of how the OO code is implemented *physically* as well. This would be an additional class diagram that shows more precisely the implementation detail. You will have far more *design choices* in this diagram -- whether to use a collection or not for orders (e.g. a list or some other collection type class), what your data access patterns are (Adapters, Managers, ORMs etc.). At this level you will most likely loose the strong aggregate notation, as at this level we are talking about classes referencing each other which is most simply denoted using basic associations. You might want to use arrows and/or dot-notation to indicate end ownership and reference directions so that it's more clear what the relationships between classes are.

So, I think your question is a classic question about levels of abstraction in models and analysis vs design. Thanks for asking it!

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation just means: "if you delete the account you need to delete the orders as well".

I also recommend to just leave the aggregation away (for most cases) since it only adds little extra semantics to your model. In this case it seems obvious to delete the order when the account is deleted. The only thing the aggregation added here is (as in most cases) some confusion or some futile discussions about the worth of that diamond.

If you have a domain where the filled diamond is used it should be documented in the modeling rules. When using the shared aggregation the documentation is even mandatory since there is no semantics per se in the specs (see box on p. 110 of UML 2.5).

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning, that there is an additional, quite valuable feature of composite aggregation: Exclusivity. Imagine a system, where orders can also be linked to an Instance of WalkInCustomer. We don't have a name or account for this customer, but while he is on the premises we somehow identify him. Using a composite aggregation then means, an Order can only be linked to an Account or a WalkInCustomer, but not both. Of course the multiplicity must then be 0..1 on the side of the diamond.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Interesting.Though I think that most people (including me) would have a general account which specializes to WalkIn and RegisteredUser for an Account. Again we have different ways to express something.

Comment: Coming to think of the `0` near the diamond. That means the element **can** exist with no reference. So not being aggregate. Which is a contradiction. Probably for what you say you have an XOR association to WalkIn and RegisteredUser? But that's merely a constraint on associations.

Comment: I also would create a Superclass in this case. However, the Classes could be so different, that there is no meaningful Superclass. And I don‘t want to add Superclasses to all compositions, just to be able to later add something. The 0..1 multiplicity allows the part to also stand alone. That can be correct, depending on the system. A person can be part of a Tourgroup or be an individual Traveller. If it is not, an additional constraint is needed.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer But then you won't have a composition. I have ever since seen lots of discussions about when is a composition a composition. But never one where you say "oh, that brought light into it".

Comment: A Composition makes a statement about the allowed instances. When I need this statement I use the composition. Additionally it says something about the behavior, namely the deletion propagation, but also other unspecified cascading behavior. The latter is the fuzzy part of the semantics. As soon as this is dominating the discussion, I recommend not to use composite aggregation, let alone shared aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how deep you want to go with UML design.

If you target code generation from UML then you probably need to add the class you mentioned.
It would look a lot like Registry Pattern:
[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioveW.png)

- You can add abstraction so you can change implementation of your DataManager (if your DataManager is third-party then just call the API from DataManagerImplementation).
- After that, depending on your implementation, once you have the list, if you need to keep it then add the association `Account -> Order`, if you can live with the list on the stack then you are good to go.

C++ instanciation example:

```
DataManagerImplementation *db = new DataManagerImplementation();
// Dependency injection
Account *acc = new Account(db);
```

Then in 'Account' class:

```
Account::Account(DataManager *db)
{
  // Fetch list at creation
  // Here 'orders' could be a member
  m_db = db;
  vector<Order*> *orders = m_db->GetOrders(this);
}
```

PS: I also recommend to put arrow (direction) on association/aggregation, otherwise it implies that the association is bi-directional and so that account has a pointer to an order list, and every order also has a pointer to an account, and I am not sure this is needed.

To edit PlantUML: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/SoWkIImgAStDuN99B4dqJSnBJ4yjyimjo4dDJSqhIIp9pCzJqDMjiLFmBqf9BK9ImuKk05Hcfw2afGHHYIbjfL2McboINsG3bj6oKz1oJoq1iuir79EJyqlpIZIve0m5a566IfYMEgJcfG0T2m00